# debian preseed(ing) = pointopoint does not work?

Tags: debian

below is an excerpt of my preseeding file:

```
d-i netcfg/get_ipaddress string 111.111.111.111
d-i netcfg/get_netmask string 0.0.0.0
d-i netcfg/get_gateway string 111.111.111.1
d-i netcfg/get_pointopoint string 111.111.111.1
d-i netcfg/confirm_static boolean true
```

But it seems that the pointpoint line is NOT be written the the final

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

file. This means this line

> pointopoint 111.111.111.1

is missing in the final interfaces file. All other data is correclty written. Are here some experts that did use this paramter and know that this works? Or could this be a bug? I would be very thankful im someone can confirm me that this option is working.

thanks very much!!!

jan

Answer (score 0):

I cannot confirm this option work but in my preseed files for advanced configuration
of the target system i use :

```
d-i preseed/late_command wget http://host/myscript.sh; sh myscript.sh
```

So myscript will be executed by d-i at the end of installation. You can for example
completly write /target/etc/network/interfaces with this kind of external scripts.
Running this way avoid to bored by some strange preseed behaviours.